# iOS - invalid provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xcode

I try upload my app but I face this error
how can I fix it

[image]

Comment: There must be a typo in your providing profile. If incase you don't know how to do it, google create a provisioning profile / tutorial of uploading a binary to iTunes. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer , you have change Provisioning Profile From automatic to iOS distribution , you can find it in

Build Setting ---> code Singing --> Provisioning Profile

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Apple Developer Portal, recreate the provisioning profile (distribution profile in your case) and download it again. Make sure that the Distribution certificate is installed in your Keychain Access in order to sign apps submitted for the App Store.

Comment: I do that but I have the same problem , what shall I do ?