# No matching provisioning profiles found... appID xxx.xxx does not match identifier xxx.xxxTests

Tags: xcode, matching, provisioning-profile, app-id

I am confused with the error I'm getting here, I created a provisioning profile for my app using the bundle identifier xxx.xxx. I set the target provisioning profile to that profile. It says that the appID for the provisioning profile is xxx.xxx which under my target, bundle identifier it is indeed xxx.xxx but then it says it doesn't match the bundle identifier xxx.xxxTests which is the test target. I'm kind of new to xcode and provisioning profiles etc, I couldn't find this issue anywhere.

Here is the exact message:
"The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“xxx Development Profile”) has an AppID of “xxx.xxx” which does not match your bundle identifier “xxx.xxxTests”.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center."

Anyone know anything about this or come across this before?

Let me know if I can clarify anything better.

Answer (score 1):

Drag provisioning profile on xcode icon..check code signing property in build settingsChoose code signing identity and provisioning profile..i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm reading you have changed your provisioning profile in your target from "xxx.xxx" to "xxx.xxxTests" which is in fact a different bundle identifier making the error valid. You really have two courses of action:

1. Change your bundle identifier back to just "xxx.xxx". This is the appropriate path of least resistance.
2. Create a new bundle identifier in the portal as "xxx.xxxTests" as well as a new provisioning profile for "xxx.xxxTests" tied to the same certificate. With XCode closed drag the new provisioning profile onto your XCode app icon then open your project.

You shouldn't have to change your bundle identifier to conduct testing. When you go to deploy you will only have to change which provisioning profile your target is compiling with (development vs distribution).

EDIT:
I have some more tips on provisioning profiles here: [How to become familiar with code signing issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434126/how-to-become-familiar-with-code-signing-issues/28660450#28660450)

The quick and dirty side of provisioning works like this:

- When you are added to the Apple Provisioning Portal your **cert** is the keys to the castle. Any code you compile has to be associated with your cert or you won't be able to properly compile/export your code.
- Your **bundle identifier** is essentially the way iOS identifies your application. Conceptually speaking if you want to install your app multiple times on the same device create multiple bundle identifiers.
- Your **provisioning profile** ties all of the pieces together. The prov profile tells XCode that you plan on using your **cert** to compile your app identified by your **bundle identifier**. If it's a development build it will only the devices specifically assigned to the prov profile in the portal will be able to install your app.

Comment: A downvote on a valid explanation with no comment? That's helpful.